# use indexpath.setion for a table with different section number

Tags: uitableview

I have two tableviews and cells are configured depending on which table view it is, they are implemented in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method via `indexpath.section`. However, the two tableviews have a different number of sections. Is there a way to go about this issue? Thanks

When i said they had different section numbers i meant the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if(tableView==byTeam) {
        return [teamnameswithoutRepeat count];
    } else {
        return [JSONPointsArray count];
    }
    // Return the number of sections.
}
```

When i use the following in `cellforrowatindexpath:`

```
label.text=[currentarray objectAtIndex: indexpath.section];
```

there is a range error because `indexpath.section` is too big, it is using the `JSONPointsArray` to determine the number of sections, however when i run the app the by team tableview has the correct amount of sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cellForRow...` method needs to be similar:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == byTeam) {
        // process the "byTeam" table using the teamnamesiwthoutRepeat array
    } else {
        // process the other table using the JSONPointsArray array
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but im not sure if you understood what i meant, i clarified my question above. thanks again

Comment: yes thats exactly what i did, but when i put: label.text=[currentarray objectAtIndex: indexpath.section]; in each if statement, one will work fine, but the other one will give me a range error. both tables have numerous sections and only one row

Comment: What is `currentArray`? Use the two arrays you actually have.

Comment: Yes but I get a range error even by doing so, for the by team I use: cell.textLabel.text=[ team nameswithoutrepeat objectatindex: indexpath.section] and I do the same thing for the other table that is:  cell.textLabel.text=[ jsonpointsarray objectatindex: indexpath.section] but I still get the error, for the JSon one it's ok, the range error is with the other one, thanks

Comment: Why don't you post the code that actually gives you the problem.

Comment: sorry, i figured out the problem. Thank you very much for your time though. My currentarray was missing an object, so it was not large enough. Best Regards